# Control.Invoke problem (x is a field but is used like a method)

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of controls which need updating from another thread. While this is obviously possible by using Control.Invoke, is there an elegant way to do this for at least 10 control assignments?

Also, what is wrong with this code?

```
InstallationStatus.Invoke(myDelegate = new AssignmentDelegate(InstallationStatus));
```

I'd like to to set the status of the label (InstallationStatus) from inside the delegate. The delegate takes an argument of type Control, the error is:

Installation is a field but is used like a method.

Thanks

Comment: There is no `Installation` in your example, so we can't really comment on "Installation is a field but is used like a method."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A delegate constructor accepts the *target method* to invoke; perhaps the most convenient approach here is:

```
InstallationStatus.Invoke(
       (MethodInvoker) delegate { InstallationStatus = blah; });
```

although other variants exist (passing the control as an argument to a formal method)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (and IMHO syntactically a bit more appealing) way of doing this is via `SynchronizationContext.Send()` which can be used like this:

```
private System.Threading.SynchronizationContext syncContext;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    syncContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;
}

private void UpdateControlsOnTheUIThread()
{
    syncContext.Send(x => 
    {
        // Do sth here..
        myControl.Property = newValue;
    }, null);
}
```

Important is to retrieve (and store) the SynchronizationContext instance at the right time. A Form's constructor is generally a good place. Within the delegate (or anonymous method) you're passing in to the Send() method, you can obviously update multiple controls.

Answer (score 0):

Here I created a sample little Windows Forms application that demonstrates setting properties dynamically at runtime using reflection. A good method to do this cleanly would be perhaps to iterate thru some collection type perhaps.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This sample shows invocation using a loosely typed object. 
        //Assumes you will send the correct object type to the property setter at runtime
        Dictionary<string, object> setupObjectValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        setupObjectValues.Add("Text", "Hello World");
        setupObjectValues.Add("ReadOnly", true);
        setupObjectValues.Add("Location", new Point(10, 5));
        foreach (string val in setupObjectValues.Keys)
        {
            UpdateControlObjectValue(textBox1, val, setupObjectValues[val]);
        }
    }
    public delegate void SetObjectPropertyDelegate(Control param, string PropertyName, object NewValue);
    public void UpdateControlObjectValue(Control sender, string PropertyName, object Value)
    {
        //Pass the method name into the delegate and match signatures
        //params collection used for parameters on method called in this case object and string
        sender.Invoke(new SetObjectPropertyDelegate(SetObjectProperty), sender, PropertyName, Value);
    }
    //Called by delegate (Matches signature of SetObjectPropertyDelegate)
    private void SetObjectProperty(Control sender, string PropertyName, object NewValue)
    {
        if (sender == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertyName) || NewValue == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Argument");
        try
        {
            //Guaranteed to be a control due to strong typing on parameter declaration
            sender.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).SetValue(sender, NewValue, null);
            //Set Value on MSDN doc : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx
        }
        catch (System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException ex)
        {
            //Two properties were found that match your Property Name
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        {
            //Null Property Found
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            //Invalid Argument
        }
        catch (System.Reflection.TargetException ex)
        {
            //Invalid Target
        }
        catch (System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException ex)
        {
            //Invalid number of parameters passed to reflection invoker
        }
        catch (System.MethodAccessException ex)
        {
            //Could not access the method to invoke it
        }
        catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            //Problem invoking the target method
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //serious problem
        }
    }
}
```

}